# How can I change html with javascript without restarting a CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I came across this cool color transition that I like:

https://codepen.io/jason-hamje/pen/pobZRjK

and I found a timer script that seems to work well:

```
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/jason-hamje/pen/mdEjRWW

But I'm struggling to combine the two.  This is the closest I've come:

https://codepen.io/jason-hamje/pen/rNLrjmb

It plays the animation but restarts every time the second changes. I think the problem is that changing the innerHTML of an element basically makes CSS think it's a whole new element?

I am a nearly-complete scrub when it comes to frontend so I'm feeling pretty lost here.  I was kind of surprised that I couldn't seem to find a similar question already asked (though that's likely because I don't know enough about frontend to know how to ask it properly).

My gut tells me that if I'm truly determined to make this work then I should just handle all of the color transitions directly in javascript, instead of trying to make a javascript loop interact with a CSS animation.  However, I figure there's a good chance that there's a simple fix, so I thought I'd post here.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close. The problem was that you were creating new  elements for each character in your timer, and that tells the browser to re-render them re-setting the animation timer. Add on single element in the HTML at the beginning, and change its contents to the timer value.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  var timer = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  //var chars = $.trim(timer).split("");

  //var container = document.getElementById("demo")
  var container = document.querySelector("#demo");
  container.querySelector("span").innerHTML = timer;
  //container.innerHTML = '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
  
setTimeout(function(){
    container.classList.remove('pre-animation')
},100)
  
  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
/*
 * Animation module with all animation code
 */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300);
.anim-text-flow,
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover {
  /*
   * Animation variables
   */
  /*
   * Elements settings
   */
  /*
   * Keyframe loop
   */
  /*
   * Element animation delay loop
   */
}
.anim-text-flow span,
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span {
  -webkit-animation-name: anim-text-flow-keys;
          animation-name: anim-text-flow-keys;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
          animation-duration: 50s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #69c9bc;
  }
  5% {
    color: #6e7ec4;
  }
  10% {
    color: #73b2bf;
  }
  15% {
    color: #a965cd;
  }
  20% {
    color: #67cbc6;
  }
  25% {
    color: #8a77bb;
  }
  30% {
    color: #6278d0;
  }
  35% {
    color: #ac70c2;
  }
  40% {
    color: #6b5dd5;
  }
  45% {
    color: #ad67cb;
  }
  50% {
    color: #6cc69c;
  }
  55% {
    color: #70a9c2;
  }
  60% {
    color: #5f5fd3;
  }
  65% {
    color: #a575bd;
  }
  70% {
    color: #cd65c1;
  }
  75% {
    color: #6e7bc4;
  }
  80% {
    color: #ba5cd6;
  }
  85% {
    color: #62aad0;
  }
  90% {
    color: #6a86c8;
  }
  95% {
    color: #68cabf;
  }
  100% {
    color: #9f5cd6;
  }
}
@keyframes anim-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #69c9bc;
  }
  5% {
    color: #6e7ec4;
  }
  10% {
    color: #73b2bf;
  }
  15% {
    color: #a965cd;
  }
  20% {
    color: #67cbc6;
  }
  25% {
    color: #8a77bb;
  }
  30% {
    color: #6278d0;
  }
  35% {
    color: #ac70c2;
  }
  40% {
    color: #6b5dd5;
  }
  45% {
    color: #ad67cb;
  }
  50% {
    color: #6cc69c;
  }
  55% {
    color: #70a9c2;
  }
  60% {
    color: #5f5fd3;
  }
  65% {
    color: #a575bd;
  }
  70% {
    color: #cd65c1;
  }
  75% {
    color: #6e7bc4;
  }
  80% {
    color: #ba5cd6;
  }
  85% {
    color: #62aad0;
  }
  90% {
    color: #6a86c8;
  }
  95% {
    color: #68cabf;
  }
  100% {
    color: #9f5cd6;
  }
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(1),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.8s;
          animation-delay: -19.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(2),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.6s;
          animation-delay: -19.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(3),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.4s;
          animation-delay: -19.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(4),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.2s;
          animation-delay: -19.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(5),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19s;
          animation-delay: -19s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(6),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.8s;
          animation-delay: -18.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(7),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.6s;
          animation-delay: -18.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(8),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.4s;
          animation-delay: -18.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(9),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.2s;
          animation-delay: -18.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(10),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18s;
          animation-delay: -18s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(11),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.8s;
          animation-delay: -17.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(12),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.6s;
          animation-delay: -17.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(13),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(13) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.4s;
          animation-delay: -17.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(14),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(14) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.2s;
          animation-delay: -17.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(15),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(15) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17s;
          animation-delay: -17s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(16),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(16) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.8s;
          animation-delay: -16.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(17),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(17) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.6s;
          animation-delay: -16.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(18),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(18) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.4s;
          animation-delay: -16.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(19),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(19) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.2s;
          animation-delay: -16.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(20),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(20) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16s;
          animation-delay: -16s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(21),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(21) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.8s;
          animation-delay: -15.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(22),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(22) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.6s;
          animation-delay: -15.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(23),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(23) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.4s;
          animation-delay: -15.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(24),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(24) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.2s;
          animation-delay: -15.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(25),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(25) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15s;
          animation-delay: -15s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(26),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(26) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.8s;
          animation-delay: -14.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(27),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(27) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.6s;
          animation-delay: -14.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(28),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(28) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.4s;
          animation-delay: -14.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(29),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(29) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.2s;
          animation-delay: -14.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(30),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(30) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14s;
          animation-delay: -14s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(31),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(31) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.8s;
          animation-delay: -13.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(32),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(32) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.6s;
          animation-delay: -13.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(33),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(33) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.4s;
          animation-delay: -13.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(34),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(34) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.2s;
          animation-delay: -13.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(35),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(35) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13s;
          animation-delay: -13s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(36),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(36) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.8s;
          animation-delay: -12.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(37),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(37) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.6s;
          animation-delay: -12.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(38),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(38) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.4s;
          animation-delay: -12.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(39),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(39) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.2s;
          animation-delay: -12.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(40),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(40) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12s;
          animation-delay: -12s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(41),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(41) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.8s;
          animation-delay: -11.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(42),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(42) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.6s;
          animation-delay: -11.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(43),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(43) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.4s;
          animation-delay: -11.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(44),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(44) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.2s;
          animation-delay: -11.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(45),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(45) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11s;
          animation-delay: -11s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(46),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(46) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.8s;
          animation-delay: -10.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(47),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(47) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.6s;
          animation-delay: -10.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(48),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(48) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.4s;
          animation-delay: -10.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(49),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(49) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.2s;
          animation-delay: -10.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(50),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(50) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10s;
          animation-delay: -10s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(51),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(51) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.8s;
          animation-delay: -9.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(52),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(52) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.6s;
          animation-delay: -9.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(53),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(53) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.4s;
          animation-delay: -9.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(54),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(54) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.2s;
          animation-delay: -9.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(55),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(55) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9s;
          animation-delay: -9s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(56),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(56) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.8s;
          animation-delay: -8.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(57),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(57) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.6s;
          animation-delay: -8.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(58),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(58) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.4s;
          animation-delay: -8.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(59),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(59) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.2s;
          animation-delay: -8.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(60),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(60) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8s;
          animation-delay: -8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(61),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(61) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.8s;
          animation-delay: -7.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(62),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(62) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.6s;
          animation-delay: -7.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(63),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(63) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.4s;
          animation-delay: -7.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(64),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(64) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.2s;
          animation-delay: -7.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(65),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(65) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7s;
          animation-delay: -7s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(66),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(66) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.8s;
          animation-delay: -6.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(67),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(67) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.6s;
          animation-delay: -6.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(68),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(68) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.4s;
          animation-delay: -6.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(69),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(69) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.2s;
          animation-delay: -6.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(70),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(70) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6s;
          animation-delay: -6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(71),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(71) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.8s;
          animation-delay: -5.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(72),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(72) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.6s;
          animation-delay: -5.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(73),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(73) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.4s;
          animation-delay: -5.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(74),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(74) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.2s;
          animation-delay: -5.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(75),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(75) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5s;
          animation-delay: -5s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(76),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(76) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.8s;
          animation-delay: -4.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(77),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(77) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.6s;
          animation-delay: -4.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(78),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(78) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.4s;
          animation-delay: -4.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(79),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(79) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.2s;
          animation-delay: -4.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(80),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(80) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
          animation-delay: -4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(81),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(81) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.8s;
          animation-delay: -3.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(82),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(82) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.6s;
          animation-delay: -3.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(83),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(83) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.4s;
          animation-delay: -3.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(84),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(84) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.2s;
          animation-delay: -3.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(85),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(85) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
          animation-delay: -3s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(86),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(86) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.8s;
          animation-delay: -2.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(87),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(87) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.6s;
          animation-delay: -2.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(88),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(88) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.4s;
          animation-delay: -2.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(89),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(89) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.2s;
          animation-delay: -2.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(90),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(90) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
          animation-delay: -2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(91),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(91) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.8s;
          animation-delay: -1.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(92),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(92) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.6s;
          animation-delay: -1.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(93),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(93) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.4s;
          animation-delay: -1.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(94),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(94) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.2s;
          animation-delay: -1.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(95),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(95) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
          animation-delay: -1s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(96),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(96) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
          animation-delay: -0.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(97),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(97) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
          animation-delay: -0.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(98),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(98) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
          animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(99),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(99) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
          animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(100),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(100) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}

body {  
  background: transparent;
  color: #999999;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.0em;
  font-size: 5em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-align: center;

}



.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.txt {
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span id="demo" class="anim-text-flow"><span>start</span></span>
</div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```